# How can I fix those errors when yum updating

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, fedora-21

I am trying to update my distro, I run a `fedora 21` and would like to update the packages.

doing
`sudo yum update`
I get at the end:

```
Total size: 1.1 G
Total download size: 45 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: Y
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for google-chrome
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.pyo: read error
(tried to read 710 bytes from offset 27268)
cannot reconstruct rpm from disk files
google-chrome-stable-42.0.2311 FAILED                                          
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/google-chrome-stable-42.0.2311.90-1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Finishing delta rebuilds of 1 package(s) (113 k)


Error downloading packages:
  Delta RPM of python-urllib3-1.10.2-1.fc21.noarch: Delta RPM rebuild failed
  google-chrome-stable-42.0.2311.90-1.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Everything stops because of those 2 little things (nothing gets installed), how can I force the installation of the rest ?
I tried `sudo yum update --skip-broken` without success

Comment: This question is off topic for SO, it is more suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply removing chrome worked, the update went through. Then I reinstalled chrome

Comment: You should accept your own answer. Better late than never!